# Jenkins Pipeline Poll SCM with different Repo for Jenkinsfile and Application Repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i need some informations to setup my Jenkinsfile correctly.

I am using a Jenkins 2.19.1 with git-plugin Version 3.0.0.

Further informations:

Jenkinsfile is in a extra Repository called repoB.
This one is checked out in the Pipeline Job Configuration.

The node.js application which i want to test, build and deliver is in repoA.

If i check in a commit in repoB i want that Jenkins does nothing, if i check in to repoA the build should start.

I have activated the "Poll SCM" Trigger in the job configuration, if this one isn't activated the build never starts on Triggers by gitblit (SCM Repo with post commit hook). The post commit hook on gitblit is only configured for repoA.

My Jenkinsfile looks similar to this one:

```
stage(git checkout){
  node{
    git branch: 'test', credentialsId: 'id', url: 'ssh://git.company.de/path/to/repo'
  }
}
stage ('test, build and deliver'){
//do some stuff here
}
```